# in which phase of JSP JSTL is evaluated?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I know the life cycle of JSP page but i wondered when i started to use JSTL. **My question is that in which phase of JSP life cycle this JSTL tags evaluates?** for example in jsp translation phase or in service phase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At [`translation phase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html)

> Custom tags are converted into calls to the tag handler that implements the custom tag.

When you execute that JSP (*which happens after successful compilation(translation)*), they actually run and render the output to response.

Answer (score 2):

JSTL is evaluated during JSP compilation (or translation) phase. You can check that by the stacktrace if an exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 8, column: 23) No tag "urfafl" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1215)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
```